# What's the difference between Entry() and Text()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

What's the difference between tkinter's `Entry()` and `Text()` functions?

Couldn't find anything online, so after figuring it out, wanted to make it available online for others.

Comment: How could you not be able to find anything online? This is literally the first thing about `Entry` and `Text` in the docs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Entry() allows one line of input:

[image]

Whereas, Text() allows multi-line inputs:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Any documentation on Tkinter will tell you the answer. In fact, it's usually literally the very first thing it will tell you.

---

[`Entry`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm) in the Tkinter Book starts off with:

> The **Entry** widget is a standard Tkinter widget used to enter or display a single line of text.
>
> ### When to use the Entry Widget
>
> The entry widget is used to enter text strings. This widget allows the user to enter one line of text, in a single font.
>
> To enter multiple lines of text, use the [Text](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm) widget.

---

[`Entry`](https://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/entry.html) in the Tkinter reference starts with:

> The purpose of an `Entry` widget is to let the user see and modify a *single* line of text.
>
> - If you want to display *multiple* lines of text that can be edited, see [Section 24, “The `Text` widget”](https://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/text.html).

---

And so on.

Answer (score 1):

The Entry widget has validation commands (ie, possibility to have only lowercase, only digits etc). This needs some workaround to make work in Text widgets.