# How can I get all text box entries into one file?

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to take each entry into the text boxes and have them print into one file, but I am not having much luck.  I have tried entry boxes, lists, and strvar, but no luck.  I have attached the input and output I would like to get back.  Any and all help, suggestions, comments, direction appreciated.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from tkinter import font
import os
import tempfile


root = Tk()

     
data_frame = LabelFrame(root, background ='#fadc91')
data_frame.pack()
    
lname_label = Label(data_frame, text = "Name, Last:", font = 'Helvetica 11 bold')
lname_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
lname = Text(data_frame, width=20, height=1)
lname.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, ipadx=40)
    
fname_label = Label(data_frame, text = "First:", font = 'Helvetica 11 bold')
fname_label.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=10, pady=10)
fname = Text(data_frame, width=20, height=1)
fname.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=10, pady=10, ipadx=40)

mname_label = Label(data_frame, text = "Middle Initial:", font = 'Helvetica 11 bold')
mname_label.grid(row=0, column=4, padx=10, pady=10)
mname = Text(data_frame, width=5, height=1)
mname.grid(row=0, column=5, padx=10, pady=10)


my_label5 = Label(root, text = "    ", font = 'Helvetica 14 bold', background ='#fadc91')
my_label5.pack()

edit_frame = LabelFrame(root, font = 'Helvetica 12 bold', background ='#fadc91')
edit_frame.pack()


def print_command(txt):
    print_item = tempfile.mktemp('.txt')
    open(print_item, 'w').write(txt)
    #os.startfile(print_item, 'print')
    os.startfile(print_item, 'open')
    

prnt_button = Button(edit_frame, text = "Print Labels", font = 'Helvetica 12 bold', background = 'light gray', command=lambda:print_command(lname.get('1.0', END)))
prnt_button.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

[input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xb6Xa.png)

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nFH4.png)

Comment: Please accept an answer if it was what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code that need to be addressed:

- You are using Text widgets for **lname**, **fname**, and **mname**, which are meant for multi-line text input. If you want single-line text input, you should use Entry widgets instead.
- When you call **lname.get('1.0', END)**, it retrieves the text from the Text widget, including the newline character (\n). You should strip the newline character to get just the text.
- You are trying to pass the text from the text widgets to the print_command function, but you need to do this for all the text widgets and format them as desired.

Here's an updated version of your code

```
from tkinter import *
import os
import tempfile

root = Tk()

data_frame = LabelFrame(root, background='#fadc91')
data_frame.pack()

lname_label = Label(data_frame, text="Name, Last:", font='Helvetica 11 bold')
lname_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
lname = Entry(data_frame)
lname.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, ipadx=40)

fname_label = Label(data_frame, text="First:", font='Helvetica 11 bold')
fname_label.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=10, pady=10)
fname = Entry(data_frame)
fname.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=10, pady=10, ipadx=40)

mname_label = Label(data_frame, text="Middle Initial:", font='Helvetica 11 bold')
mname_label.grid(row=0, column=4, padx=10, pady=10)
mname = Entry(data_frame)
mname.grid(row=0, column=5, padx=10, pady=10)

my_label5 = Label(root, text="    ", font='Helvetica 14 bold', background='#fadc91')
my_label5.pack()

edit_frame = LabelFrame(root, font='Helvetica 12 bold', background='#fadc91')
edit_frame.pack()


def print_command():
    # Get the text from widgets
    last_name = lname.get()
    first_name = fname.get()
    middle_initial = mname.get()

    # Format the data
    formatted_data = f"Last Name: {last_name}\nFirst Name: {first_name}\nMiddle Initial: {middle_initial}"

    # Write result to a temporary text file
    print_item = tempfile.mktemp('.txt')
    with open(print_item, 'w') as file:
        file.write(formatted_data)

    # Open the text file
    os.startfile(print_item, 'open')


prnt_button = Button(edit_frame, text="Print Labels", font='Helvetica 12 bold', background='light gray', command=print_command)
prnt_button.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

**Output :**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @achrafbesalah!  I greatly appreciate it!!

Comment: Thanks all for the help, I tried all and went with this one as it got me where I needed for printing down the road.  Thanks again!!

Comment: You are welcome. Plz don't forget to accept the answer and up vote

Answer (score 0):

You could append it into a file like so.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from tkinter import font
import os
import tempfile

root = Tk()

data_frame = LabelFrame(root, background='#fadc91')
data_frame.pack()

lname_label = Label(data_frame, text="Name, Last:", font='Helvetica 11 bold')
lname_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
lname = Text(data_frame, width=20, height=1)
lname.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, ipadx=40)

fname_label = Label(data_frame, text="First:", font='Helvetica 11 bold')
fname_label.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=10, pady=10)
fname = Text(data_frame, width=20, height=1)
fname.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=10, pady=10, ipadx=40)

mname_label = Label(data_frame, text="Middle Initial:", font='Helvetica 11 bold')
mname_label.grid(row=0, column=4, padx=10, pady=10)
mname = Text(data_frame, width=5, height=1)
mname.grid(row=0, column=5, padx=10, pady=10)

my_label5 = Label(root, text="    ", font='Helvetica 14 bold', background='#fadc91')
my_label5.pack()

edit_frame = LabelFrame(root, font='Helvetica 12 bold', background='#fadc91')
edit_frame.pack()


def get_line_for_file():
    with open("names_file.txt", "a") as out_file:
        out_file.write(f"{lname.get('1.0','end-1c')}, {fname.get('1.0','end-1c')} {mname.get('1.0','end-1c')}\n")


prnt_button = Button(edit_frame, text="Print Labels", font='Helvetica 12 bold', background='light gray',
                     command= get_line_for_file)
prnt_button.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you for the info @prezt.  It is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided create a file with only the text in `lname` because that is what you passes to the `print_command` using the lambda function.

```
prnt_button = Button(... command=lambda:print_command(lname.get('1.0', END)))
```

You need to add the text from all the other text entries as well:

`prnt_button`:

```py
prnt_button = Button(edit_frame, text = "Print Labels", font = 'Helvetica 12 bold', background = 'light gray', command=lambda:print_command(
    lname.get('1.0', END), 
    fname.get('1.0', END), 
    mname.get('1.0', END)))
```

If you want your `print_command` function to be more versatile you can:

```
def print_command(*args):
    print_item = tempfile.mktemp('.txt')
    with open(print_item, 'w') as file:
        for i in args:
            file.write(i)
    os.startfile(print_item, 'open')
```

**OR**

```
def print_command(*args):
    print_item = tempfile.mktemp('.txt')
    with open(print_item, 'w') as file:
        out = ''
        for i in args:
            out += f'{i.strip()},'
        file.write(out[:-1])
    os.startfile(print_item, 'open')
```

---

**But** if the format you attached is important, you can also do the following:

```
def print_command(l_name, f_name, m_name):
    print_item = tempfile.mktemp('.txt')
    with open(print_item, 'w') as file:
        file.write(f'{l_name}, {f_name} {m_name}')
    os.startfile(print_item, 'open')
```

---

You can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50194711/whats-the-difference-between-entry-and-text) about the difference between `Text` and `Entry` but you can get text from both, it just depends on what you need.

> Entry() allows one line of input

> Whereas, Text() allows multi-line inputs

Comment: @marcspector1972 If my answer helped you, please consider upvoting and accepting the answer :)